# JGit and finding the Head

Tags: java, git, scala, jgit

I'm trying to get my hands on the HEAD commit with JGit:

```
val builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
val repo = builder.setGitDir(new File("/www/test-repo"))
  .readEnvironment()
  .findGitDir()
  .build()

val walk: RevWalk = new RevWalk(repo, 100)

val head: ObjectId = repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD)
val headCommit: RevCommit = walk.parseCommit(head)
```

I find that it opens the repo fine, but `head` value is set to `null`. I wonder why it can't find HEAD?

I'm reading this documentation: http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide

The repository is constructed just like the doc says, and the `RevWalk` as well. I'm using the latest version of JGit which is `2.0.0.201206130900-r` from http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven.

My question: what do I need to change in my code to get JGit to return actual instances of `RevCommit` instead of `null` like it now does?

**Update:** This code:

```
val git = new Git(repo)
val logs: Iterable[RevCommit] = git.log().call().asInstanceOf[Iterable[RevCommit]]
```

Gives me this exception: `No HEAD exists and no explicit starting revision was specified`

The exception is odd, because a simple `git rev-parse HEAD` tells me `0b0e8bf2cae9201f30833d93cc248986276a4d75`, which means there is a HEAD in the repository. I've tried different repositories, mine and from other people.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know the answer to this question. I just have a comment that rather than saying "I'm using the latest version of JGit" you should state the exact version number. What if someone with a similar problem reads this question a year from now? How will they know which version was "the latest version" when you originally asked the question?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to point to the Git metadata directory (probably `/www/test-repo/.git`) when you call `setGitDir`, not to the working directory (`/www/test-repo`).

I have to admit I'm not sure what `findGitDir` is supposed to do, but I've run into this problem before and specifying the `.git` directory worked.

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure I never got the mechanics of this) that more specifically, he should use either setGitDir or findGitDir, not both. But yeah I've been through a lot of troubles before finding the right combination.

Comment: I've just confirmed that specifying the metadata directory with `setGitDir` works, and it doesn't seem to make any difference whether you add `findGitDir` or not.

Comment: And here's an example: https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/OpenRepository.java

Answer (score 6):

For the completeness sake, here is a fully working example how to get the hash for the HEAD commit:

```
public String getHeadName(Repository repo) {
  String result = null;
  try {
    ObjectId id = repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD);
    result = id.getName();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me (using 4.5.0.201609210915-r) the solution was to use just `RepositoryBuilder` instead of `FileRepositoryBuilder`.  Until I made this change all methods were returning `null`.

```
rb = new org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RepositoryBuilder()
    .readEnvironment()
    .findGitDir()
    .build();

headRef = rb.getRef(rb.getFullBranch());
headHash = headRef.getObjectId().name();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `val git: Git = Git.open( new File( "/www/test-repo" ) )`. JGit will then scan the given folder for the git meta directory (usually `.git`). If it fails to find this folder, an `IOException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much info available for the usage of findGitDir(), so I thought I share my findings here. So use this code to setup JGit Repository object from anywhere of its working tree:

```java
RepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new RepositoryBuilder();

Repository repo = repositoryBuilder
  .findGitDir(new File("~/workspace/project1/src/main/java"))
  .setMustExist(true)
  .build();
```

In my case I was using the repo to check its status:

```java
Git git = Git.wrap(repo);
git.status().call();
```

The code is based on JGit version 5.10.0.202012080955-r