# JGit Check if a branch is checked out

Tags: java, jgit

I am working on a project using JGit. I managed to delete a branch, but I also want to check if that branch is checked out or not. I found a variable in `CheckoutCommand` but it is private:

```
private boolean isCheckoutIndex() {
    return startCommit == null && startPoint == null;
}
```

No public method returns what I want. When I use the command below on a checked out branch it returns an error that the branch cannot be deleted, so I want to check first if is checked out or not.

```
git.branchDelete().setForce(true).setBranchNames(branchName).call();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Repository::getFullBranch()` returns the full name (e.g. `refs/heads/main`) of the currently checked out branch, if any. Otherwise the ID of the HEAD commit is returned or `null`, if there is no commit.

Comment: Works fine! I have one more question. How get the commit message when ammend button is pressed?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342152/jgit-and-finding-the-head) for how to use `Repository#resolve()` and `RevWalk` to obtain the commit id of a ref. Note that you should dispose of the `RevWalk`after using it with `revWalk.dispose()`.

Comment: A sample about how to get the commit message for a given commit is now available in the jgit-cookbook at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/GetCommitMessage.java