# How to fetch the value of bitbucket branch name pulled in my workspace, using java

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm working on a java project. For updating the nexus link dynamically I need to know which branch I'm doing the build, based on that I will fetch snapshot or ear from nexus.

I tried using Jgit to fetch it, but I managed to fetch all the branch from the repo, not the one pulled in the local workspace.

```
Collection<Ref> refs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
                         .setHeads(true)
                         .setRemote("My git link").setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                         .call();

for (Ref ref : refs) {
                     branches.add(ref.getName().substring(ref.getName().lastIndexOf("/")+1, ref.getName().length()));
                 }
                 Collections.sort(branches);
                 List<String> list1 =  branches;
                 for(String abc:list1){
                     System.out.println(abc);
                 }
```

I'm trying to fetch the current pulled branch not all the branch present in the repo.

Comment: You want the branch that's currently checked out?

Comment: Yeah, the current checked out one.

Comment: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`

Comment: [See this answer for how to do it with JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992944/2729876)